# numpy array to scipy.sparse matrix

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

Given an arbitrary numpy array (`ndarray`), is there a function or a short way to convert it to a `scipy.sparse` matrix?

I'd like something that works like:

```
A = numpy.array([0,1,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0])
S = to_sparse(A, type="csr_matrix")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually do something like

```
>>> import numpy, scipy.sparse
>>> A = numpy.array([[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]])
>>> Asp = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)
>>> Asp
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: Hm, that was easy, I should have tried that. I didn't expect the constructor to do the conversion. This works for the constructors of the other sparse matrix types, too.

Answer (score 4):

A very useful and pertinent example is in the help!

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
help(sp)
```

This gives:

```
Example 2
---------

Construct a matrix in COO format:

>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> from numpy import array
>>> I = array([0,3,1,0])
>>> J = array([0,3,1,2])
>>> V = array([4,5,7,9])
>>> A = sparse.coo_matrix((V,(I,J)),shape=(4,4))
```

It's also worth noting the various constructors are (again from the help):

```
    1. csc_matrix: Compressed Sparse Column format
    2. csr_matrix: Compressed Sparse Row format
    3. bsr_matrix: Block Sparse Row format
    4. lil_matrix: List of Lists format
    5. dok_matrix: Dictionary of Keys format
    6. coo_matrix: COOrdinate format (aka IJV, triplet format)
    7. dia_matrix: DIAgonal format

To construct a matrix efficiently, use either lil_matrix (recommended) or
dok_matrix. The lil_matrix class supports basic slicing and fancy
indexing with a similar syntax to NumPy arrays.
```

Your example would be as simple as:

```
S = sp.csr_matrix(A)
```

Comment: @clstaudt I'm not sure what you are looking for, `sp.csr_matrix(A)` would construct a `csr` type matrix from a dense numpy array `A`, while `sp.csc_matrix(A)` would construct a type `csc` matrix, etc... The constructors _are_ the efficient conversion functions you are looking for (though read the caveats in the help).

Comment: You're right, the constructors do the conversions I was looking for. I expected them to take only arguments that correspond to the way entries are stored, like: A = sparse.coo_matrix((V,(I,J)),shape=(4,4))

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65017153/9979257

In this answer, I have explained how to convert a 2-dimensional NumPy matrix into CSR or CSC format.