# Why does the numpy.zeros() matrix get false in scipy.sparse.issparse()?

Tags: numpy, scipy

I created matrix by `np.zeros()`, and tested it with `sp.issparse()`. Why I get false even the matrix is zero (or in case of mostly zero matrix as well)?

Comment: This `issparse` tests the matrix class, not the proportion of 0s

Comment: The code for this function is just: `isinstance(x, sparse.spmatrix)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sparse matrix has a different memory representation: it is not the cells being zero that matters but the fact that the cells are allocated in memory.

`np.zeros()` allocates all fields of the array in memory, even those being zero, while a sparse matrix does not.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922487/how-to-transform-numpy-matrix-or-array-to-scipy-sparse-matrix) for how to convert from a numpy matrix/array to a sparse matrix.